# limit detection angle of a motion sensor light switch

Tags: switch, light

Is there a way to limit the horizontal angle of a motion based indoor (occupancy) light switch to it doesn't  pick up movement within, say 90 degree horizontal angle only

Comment: What make/model is said motion-sensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the same thing for a motion sensor in my alarm system. A window in the corner of the view was causing false alarms.

I am assuming that your sensor is similar, it has a semicircular translucent cover over the IR sensor. I disassembled mine and put black electrical tape on the back side of the translucent cover to block part of the view.

You could also put tape on the front, but it won't look as nice.

Comment: I like this idea, but I wouldn't use electrical tape. It gets gooey when it's warm and may slough off. Aluminum foil tape would be great.